# PHP Form implode / explode

Tags: php

I am using the a db field merchant_sku_item in a form. the original value is separated by / in the db like this:

```
2*CC689/1*CC368-8/1*SW6228-AB
```

I want to display in a text area on each line so I tried like this:

```
   <textarea name="merchant_sku_item" rows="5" class="form-control" id="merchant_sku_item"><?
               $items=explode('/',$merchant_sku_item); 
                foreach($items as $item){
                    echo $item."\r\n";
                    } 
    ?></textarea>
```

All works fine:

```
2*CC689
1*CC368-8
1*SW6228-AB
```

but when I post the form I get a value like this:

```
2*CC689 1*CC368-8 1*SW6228-AB
```

but I wan't it back in the original format to update the DB in the correct format:

```
2*CC689/1*CC368-8/1*SW6228-AB
```

I tried to implode it with the / but I think it's just one string now so it's not working. I could replace the spaces I guess but this will not work if the field contains spaces.

Could somebody please tell me the best way to handle this?

Comment: You should normalize your db structure. This is a terrible idea to store multiple items in a field and will lead to many more nightmares than this while querying the data

Comment: don't forget to block `/` in client and server to prevent the user from using them and breaking things !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The explode is correct, but you cannot just `echo $item . "\r\n"` because if `$item` contains `</textarea>` or whatever HTML you'll skrew up the page. You have to use **`echo htmlspecialchars($item) . "\n";`**. Normally, HTML pages have Linux line endings with `"\n"` and not Windows line endings with `"\r\n"`.

To re-create the value for the DB, you have to take in consideration that the user may add some spaces or new lines. So you might not just get `"\r\n"` between the values but also `"   \n"` or I don't know what. This is why a regular expression will be more flexible than a simple `explode()`.

**The regular expression pattern**: `\s+`

The pattern `\s` will match any space, tab or new line chars. If you add the `+` sign after, it means that it can be 1 or multiple times. So this means that *`"  \r\n"`* will match as it contains spaces, a carriege return and a new line. In PHP, you put the pattern between a delimiter char that you choose and that you put at the begin and the end. Commonly it's a slash so it becomes `/\s+/`. But you sometimes see also `#\s+#` or `~\s+~`. After this delimiter, you can put some flags to change the way the regular expression is executed. Typically `/hello/i` will match *`"Hello"`* or *`"hello"`* because the `i` flag makes the search case-**i**nsensitive.

Similar to what you did: explode and re-implode example:

```php
<?php

// Example of values that could be posted because users are always
// stupid and add spaces that they then don't see anymore.
$examples = [
  "2*CC689 1*CC368-8  1*SW6228-AB", // spaces
  "2*CC689\n1*CC368-8\n1*SW6228-AB", // new lines
  "2*CC689\r\n1*CC368-8\r\n1*SW6228-AB", // carriege returns and new lines
  "2*CC689\n 1*CC368-8  \n1*SW6228-AB", // new lines and spaces
];

foreach ($examples as $merchant_sku_item) {
  $values = preg_split('/\s+/', $merchant_sku_item);
  $merchant_sku_item_for_db = implode('/', $values);
  echo $merchant_sku_item_for_db . "\n";
}
    
?>
```

Output:

```
2*CC689/1*CC368-8/1*SW6228-AB
2*CC689/1*CC368-8/1*SW6228-AB
2*CC689/1*CC368-8/1*SW6228-AB
2*CC689/1*CC368-8/1*SW6228-AB
```

**Simplier, you could also just do a replacement with the same regular expression** like this:

```php
<?php

// Example of values that could be posted.
$examples = [
  "2*CC689 1*CC368-8  1*SW6228-AB", // spaces
  "2*CC689\n1*CC368-8\n1*SW6228-AB", // new lines
  "2*CC689\r\n1*CC368-8\r\n1*SW6228-AB", // carriege returns and new lines
  "2*CC689\n 1*CC368-8  \n1*SW6228-AB", // new lines and spaces
];

foreach ($examples as $merchant_sku_item) {
  $merchant_sku_item_for_db = preg_replace('/\s+/', '/', $merchant_sku_item);
  echo $merchant_sku_item_for_db . "\n";
}
    
?>
```

And just another important point regarding the data the user could input: ***What happens if the user types `"2*CC/689"` in the textarea?***

Well, this will break your DB value :-/

This means that **you have to validate the user input** with some checks:

```php
<?php

header('Content-Type: text/plain');

$examples = [
  "2*CC689 1*CC368-8  1*SW6228-AB", // spaces
  "2*CC689\n1*CC368-8\n1*SW6228-AB", // new lines
  "2*CC689\r\n1*CC368-8\r\n1*SW6228-AB", // carriege returns and new lines
  "2*CC689\n 1*CC368-8  \n1*SW6228-AB", // new lines and spaces
  // Test with invalid datas:
  "2*C/C689\n1*CC368-8\n1*SW6228-AB", // slash not allowed
  "*CC689\n1*CC368-8\n1*SW6228-AB", // missing number before the *
  "1*\n1*CC368-8\n1*SW62?28-AB", // missing product identifier and invalid ?
  "1CC689 1*CC368-8 1SW6228-AB", // missing *
];

foreach ($examples as $example_nbr => $merchant_sku_item) {
  echo str_repeat('=', 80) . "\n";
  echo "Example $example_nbr\n\$merchant_sku_item = \"$merchant_sku_item\"\n";
  $values = preg_split('/\s+/', $merchant_sku_item);
  
  $errors = [];
  foreach ($values as $i => $value) {
    echo "Value $i = \"$value\"";
    // Pattern: a number followed by * and followed by a product id (length between 3 and 10).
    if (!preg_match('/^\d+\*[\d\w-]{3,10}$/i', $value)) {
      echo " <-- ERROR\n";
      $errors[] = $value;
    } else {
      echo "\n"; // It's ok
    }
  }
  
  if (!empty($errors)) {
    // You should handle the error and reload the form with the posted value and an error
    // message explaining to the user what format is allowed.
    echo "ERROR: Cannot save the value because the following products are wrong:\n";
    echo implode("\n", $errors) . "\n";
  }
}

?>
```

Test it here: https://onecompiler.com/php/3xtff6nk8

Comment: Wow, that is a fantastic answer, thanks so much!

Comment: @Paul Thanks for the comment! I'm glad it helped. Regular expressions are just so useful ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `preg_replace` for your final post string like below code

```
$str = "2*CC689 blue 1*CC368-8 red 1*SW6228-AB";
$items = preg_replace('/\s+/', '/', $str);
echo $items;
```

output

```
2*CC689/blue/1*CC368-8/red/1*SW6228-AB
```

I Hope understand your question exactly.

Comment: Thank you, yes I have thought of this way but sometimes the field will contain spaces for example:
2*CC689 blue 1*CC368-8 red 1*SW6228-AB

Comment: Please, Try with `preg_replace` i update my answer @Paul

Answer (score -1):

Try replacing the created spaces and removing newline characters like so:

```
<?php
   $merchant_sku_item = str_replace("\r\n","/",trim($_POST["merchant_sku_item"]));
?>
```

Comment: @Paul It may be problematic if the user leaves somes spaces at the end of a line. Putting the `"\r\n"` in the str_replace() might miss some cases :-/

Answer (score -1):

Make it this way:

```
<textarea name="merchant_sku_item" rows="5" class="form-control" id="merchant_sku_item"><?
               $items=explode('//',$merchant_sku_item); 
                foreach($items as $item){
                    echo $item."\r\n";
                    } 
    ?></textarea>
```

Comment: yeah, it will work fine, the first / is to delimitate and the second / is to add it back. You can test it out

Comment: could you please test this before marking me down. i tested it before posting it!

Comment: Tested: does not work because you did not read the question completely. The explode works fine in the original code as it produces several lines and **removes the slashes to replace them with new lines like he wants**. It's once the data is posted back that @Paul wants to replace the new lines back with the slash. Your `explode('//', $merchant_sku_item)` is equivalent to `explode('#####', $merchant_sku_item)` simply because `//` doesn't exist in the string so it returns one single item which is the original string. It doesn't contain the new lines that he wants in the textarea!